# How to make date1 == date2 if date2 > Date.current?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make `:deadline` == `date_started` if `:date_started` is set for after `Date.current`?

### db

```
create_table "challenges", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "action"
  t.datetime "date_started"
  t.date     "deadline" # This is nil upon create
end
```

### challenge.rb

```
def date_started_sets_deadline
  if self.date_started > Date.current
    self.deadline = self.date_started
  end
end
```

### Full modal as per request

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three, :dot_set_tag_owner

  CATEGORY = ['One-Shot', 'Ongoing']

  serialize :committed, Array

  acts_as_taggable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notes
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comments
  has_many :missed_dates, -> { order(:id) }
  has_many :challenge_likes
  has_many :likers, through: :challenge_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  has_many :commentators, -> { distinct }, through: :comments, source: :user

  #before_save :set_tag_owner, :unless => :dot_set_tag_owner
  before_save :date_started_sets_deadline

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  scope :oneshot,  -> { where(categories: 'One-Shot') }
  scope :ongoing,  -> { where(categories: 'Ongoing') }
  scope :deadline_not_present, -> { where(deadline: nil) }
  scope :deadline_present, -> { where.not(deadline: nil) }
  scope :date_started_not_present, -> { where(date_started: nil) }
  scope :date_started_present, -> { where.not(date_started: nil) }
  scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
  scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: nil) }
  scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
  scope :incomplete, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Time.current.beginning_of_day)}
  scope :unarchived, -> { where(archive: false) }
  scope :archived, -> { order("deadline").limit(20) }

  def date_started_sets_deadline
    if self.date_started.is_a?(DateTime)
      started = self.date_started.to_date
      if started > Date.current
        self.deadline = started
      end
    end
  end

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{action}".parameterize
  end

  def refresh_freebie
    if Date.sunday
      challenge.freebie = 0
      challenge.freebie_date = nil
    end
  end

  def days_left_challenged
    self.days_challenged - ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end + self.missed_days
  end

  def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.current.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|    
      Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end

  def days_done_challenged
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.missed_days
  end   

  def days_left_challenged
    self.days_challenged - ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end + self.missed_days
  end

  def challenge_progress
    days_done_challenged / (days_done_challenged + days_left_challenged).to_f * 100
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You flagged your question as ruby-on-rails, so I would suggest to use the `before_save` callback in your model. if `date_started` is set you can convert it to a date and check it against the current date. May be there's a more readable implementation.

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save : date_started_sets_deadline

  private      

  def date_started_sets_deadline
    if self.date_started.is_a?(DateTime)
      started = self.date_started.to_date
      if started > Date.current
        self.deadline = started
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you could have a callback hell in your model, but it isn't. What happens, if you play around at `rails c`. What if you do something like `challenge = Challenge.create(...important parameter hash ...)` and what's in `challenge.errors` after the creation?

Comment: Are you sure `date_started` is set for the challenge, because I don't see any validation (for example: `validates :date_started, presence: true`) for it?

Comment: Hm, the only idea I have is to use the gem `byebug` or `pry` with `binding.pry` to inspect the method, to see it will be called and to check the inner values. I would try to understand why the value isn't set. And I think, the best way is to write a unit test at first. This is often the best you can do to analyze such problems.

Comment: I got it Guitarman :) I used my method, but I forgot `before_save : date_started_sets_deadline`. Thanks for your help!